# Polynomial-Time Solvability Through NP-Completeness Reductions

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions

Let A and B be NP-complete problems. Suppose I have established reductions from problem A to problem B and vice versa. Now, considering a specific instance (or set of instances) of problem A that can be solved efficiently in polynomial time, does this imply that the instances reduced to problem B can also be solved in polynomial time? In other words, does the polynomial-time solvability of instances of problem A extend to instances of problem B through the established reductions?

Comment: I would say no, unless the particular reduction is a restriction or isomorphism that preserves the particular property of A which is “easier” to solve. Otherwise, there’s no guarantee that the corresponding subset of B after the reduction can be solved efficiently. It’s possible that what you’re describing is a separate complexity class (I do not know). I’m just kicking off the discussion.

Comment: One way to think about this is to define a problem A' that contains those instances of A that have the special structure that makes them efficiently solvable.  Let problem B' contain those instances of B that, if given to the reduction from B to A, produce an instance of A'.  Then B' is also polynomially solvable: both A' and B' are in P.  What exactly B' will look like may or may not be easy to say.